# error= configured to prefer settings resadpositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Tags: java, android, gradle

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPeD.png here it is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i highlight it the proplem